# Getting current context from within Package

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I had something like the following in my notebook.

```
test1[g_] := (g == 5);
test2[g_] := (g == 6);
tests={"test1", "test2"}
ToExpression[#][5] & /@ tests
```

When I put this code in a package it doesn't work because `test1` is now called `MyPackage'Private'test1`. How can I modify the last line to make this code run both inside package and inside notebook?

**Update**
Here's why I was doing doing ToExpression as opposed to using Symbols. In retrospect, maybe it's easier to use Symbols instead

I had a function which I call like `getGraphs["LeafFree","Planar",!"Tree",...]` to get all graphs that are leaf free, planar and not trees. Some of those strings are classes in `GraphData`, while others were my own classes. For each of my own classes I had a function with identical name, like `LeafFree` that tested the property. In the notebook, using `ToExpression` code like above was the quickest way to implement this.

```
getGraphs[n_Integer, cl__] := getGraphs[{n, n}, cl];
getGraphs[{nmin_Integer, nmax_Integer}, cl__] := 
 Module[{maxgraphnum = 100},
  customClasses = {"isLeafFree", ! "isLeafFree"};
  classes = {cl}\[Backslash]customClasses;
  builtinClasses = 
   GraphData["Classes"] \[Tilde] (Not /@ GraphData["Classes"]);
  Assert[classes \[Subset] builtinClasses];
  isLeafFree[gname_] := 
   FreeQ[GraphData[gname, "DegreeSequence"], 0 | 1];

  posClasses = Cases[classes\[Backslash]customClasses, _String];
  posGroup = 
   If[posClasses == {}, GraphData[nmin ;; nmax], 
    GraphData[posClasses, nmin ;; nmax]];
  negClasses = classes\[Backslash]posClasses;
  negGroups = GraphData[#[[1]], nmin ;; nmax] & /@ negClasses;

  result = Complement[posGroup, Sequence @@ negGroups];
  customTest[g_] := 
   And @@ (ToExpression[#][g] & /@ ({cl} \[Intersection] 
        customClasses));
  (*result=Take[result,Min[Length[result],100]];*)

  result = Select[result, customTest]
  ]
```

Comment: Have you tried `StringJoin[Context[], #] & /@ {"test1", "test2"}`

Comment: I would consider `ToExpression` to be bad style **ducks**. Is there a reason for using string instead of symbols?? I would consider `testsAsSymbols = {test1, test2}` and 
`Through[testsAsSymbols[5]]` much nicer -- and it would work in both cases?

Comment: @Janus: You should make that an answer...

Comment: Ha! Everybody is shy today :)

Comment: belisarius: yes, doesn't work, see my comments below. Janus: I was using ToExpression because I'm doing something like `MyPackage'doChecks[{"test1","test2"}]` where `test1` is a name of function defined inside the function `doChecks`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the comments above that you should perhaps have a compelling reason to do this, but here goes. Here is a code I use in such cases, which allows your symbol to be parsed in whatever context you like, at run-time:

```
SetAttributes[ParseTimeNameSpaceWrapper,HoldFirst];
Options[ParseTimeNameSpaceWrapper] = {
  LocalizingContext->"MyLocalizingContext`",
  DefaultImportedContexts:>{"Imported1`", "Imported2`"},
  ExtraImportedContexts:>   {}
};



ParseTimeNameSpaceWrapper[code_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
Module[{result,
  context = OptionValue[LocalizingContext],
  defcontexts = OptionValue[DefaultImportedContexts],
  extraContexts = OptionValue[ExtraImportedContexts],
  allContexts},
  allContexts = {Sequence@@defcontexts,Sequence@@extraContexts};
  BeginPackage[context,If[allContexts==={},Sequence@@{},allContexts]];      
    result = code;  
  EndPackage[];
  result
];
```

You can use options to specify some contexts where these symbols exist, that you want to import during the parse stage. You can call this from any package or notebook, and the symbol will be parsed according to whatever context you specify.

HTH

Edit:

Responding to a comment (since it made the question more specific): There is no question that at run-time `Context[]` will display whatever is the current context from where the function was called (Global in that case). I meant something else: `Context` has a syntax `Context[symbol]`, to give a context of any symbol if it is on the `$ContextPath`. For example, `Context[getGraphs]` returns `Bulatov'showGraphs'`. Therefore, if you need to determine the context of some exported function automatically, you call `Context[function]`. You can use this to construct full names of other (private) functions of that package. Here is a self - contained example:

```
In[1]:= 
BeginPackage["MyTest`"]; 
f[x_, y_, context_: Context[f]] :=
  Module[{f1str = "function1", f2str = "function2", f1, f2}, 
    {f1, f2} = ToExpression[context <> "Private`" <> #] & /@ {f1str, f2str};
    f1[x, y];
    f2[x, y];];

Begin["`Private`"];

function1[x_, y_] :=  Print["In function1: arguments are ", x, " , ", y];
function2[x_, y_] :=  Print["In function2: arguments are ", x, " , ", y];

End[]
EndPackage[];

Out[6]= "MyTest`Private`"

In[8]:= f[1, 2]

During evaluation of In[8]:= In function1: arguments are 1 , 2

During evaluation of In[8]:= In function2: arguments are 1 , 2
```

where `x,y` are just some sample arguments. Then, you never actually supply the last argument, but you can use the `context` variable inside your function, to construct long names for your other functions, as in the sample code above. Or you could just plain use Context[f] inside body of the function, and not add any arguments to it.

Comment: The problem is that I don't see a way to get correct context. I have functions `f`,`g`,`h`. `f` is put into `Global` context on `Needs` whereas `g` and `h` remain in `MyPackage'Private`. Ideally `f` would obtain the name of the package programmatically, but it's not in `Context[]` during execution of `f`

Comment: @Yaroslav: Importing a function into a Global` context does not make it belong to Global`. Its context is still the same as before. It is just that for symbols from contexts on the $ContextPath, we can use short names. If I understood correctly and `f` belongs to the same package as `g` and `h` (just not `Private` subpackage), then you can just do Context[f] <> "Private`" to reconstruct the context where `g`and `h` are, and then construct their long names, and feed them to ToExpression (of course, Context[symbol] will work reliably only when there is no shadowing, which I assume is true).

Comment: If I put `Print[Context[]]` inside f[], and I get `Global` printed even though f is defined inside a package, here's self-contained example -- http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/shifrin.zip

Comment: @Yaroslav I updated my post, hopefully this clarifies what I meant. Also, my apologies for leaving now, it is 4:50 a.m. at SPb. currently.

Answer (score 4):

`ToExpression` uses the current binding of `$Context` when creating symbols, so you can force your expression to be interpreted within a particular context thus:

```
Block[{$Context="MyPackage`Private`"}, ToExpression[#][5]] & /@ tests
```

I'm not sure I understand the circumstances of the original question.  You can get the current context using `$Context` or `Context[]`... but `ToExpression` will automatically use the current context without intervention.

If I run the exhibited code in a notebook, it works fine.  If I run it like this:

```
Begin["MyPackage`Private`"]
test1[g_] := (g == 5);
test2[g_] := (g == 6);
tests = {"test1", "test2"}
ToExpression[#][5] & /@ tests
End[]
```

... it also works fine.  I can get it to fail if I run it like this:

```
(* in the package file *)
Begin["MyPackage`Private`"]
test1[g_] := (g == 5);
test2[g_] := (g == 6);
End[]

(* in the notebook *)
tests = {"test1", "test2"}
ToExpression[#][5] & /@ tests
```

... which not only fails but also creates spurious symbols in the notebook's context.  You can work around this problem using the `Block` recipe from above.

If you want to capture the context that was in effect at the moment the package code was loaded, you can do something like this:

```
(* in the package *)
Begin["MyPackage`Private`"]
test1[g_] := (g == 5);
test2[g_] := (g == 6);
tests = {"test1", "test2"};
With[{context = $Context},
  runTests[] := Block[{$Context = context}, ToExpression[#][5]] & /@ tests
]
End[]

(* in the notebook *)
MyPackage`Private`runTests[]
```

`runTests` uses `With` to inject the private package context into its definition.

As Janus' noted, it is better to use symbols than strings since they automatically manage the whole context issue -- but this assumes your actual use case will permit the use of symbols.

Comment: The reason `Context[]` doesn't work is because the enclosing function is put into Global` context on `Needs`, so `Context[]` is Global at that point of execution, meanwhile test1,test2 are "internal" functions, so they remain in MyPackage`Private` context

Comment: The method with `Block` at the top of your answer is simple and elegant, but will (silently) fail if the symbol with the same short (string) name does exist in some of the contexts currently on the $ContextPath (which does not necessarily imply shadowing). A simple example of this would be: `f[x_] := x^2; Block[{$Context = "Test'Private'"}, ToExpression["f"][x]]`. This is one of the reasons why I use `BeginPackage - EndPackage` in my answer - they take care of this problem. Or, you could use  `Block[{$Context = 
   "Test'Private'", $ContextPath = {"Test'", "System'"}},...]` explicitly.