# Why doesn't this use of Begin[] work?

Tags: parsing, wolfram-mathematica, symbols

If we evaluate these lines *one-by-one*, `x` will be created in the context `cc`.

```
Begin["cc`"];
x = 1;
End[]
```

However, if we evaluate them together,

```
(Begin["cc`"];
x = 1;
End[])
```

then `x` will be created in `Global`.  This is despite the following printing `` cc` ``:

```
(Begin["cc`"];
Print[$Context];
End[])
```

**What is the reason for this behaviour?**  My guess is that contexts only matter during the parsing phase, not evaluation.

Use case: I wanted to create a palette `Button` that will define some symbols if they don't exist yet, in a "private" context to avoid conflict with globals.  **What is the preferred method to do this**, other than putting all the definitions in a package file and loading them from the palette? (I'd like to keep the palette self-contained.)

Comment: I just read in that docs that "The interpretation of symbol names depends on context. `Begin` thus affects the parsing of input expressions."  That answers my first question.  The second one still stands.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Symbols (and their contexts) are created when parsing, not evaluation.  If we use `$NewSymbol` we can see this in effect:

```
$NewSymbol=Print["Name: ",#1," Context: ",#2]&;

Print["first"];
test1;
Print["last"]

(Print["first"];
 test2;
 Print["last"])
```

The first one prints:

```
first
Name: test1 Context: Global`
last
```

because each line in the cell is treated as a separate input.  The second one uses parentheses to force all three lines to be considered one input and prints

```
Name: test2 Context: Global`
first
last
```

from which we can see that `test2` was created in the `` Global` `` context before any evaluation occurred.

I think the easiest way to work with this is to use an explicit context on your symbol: `` cc`x = 1 ``.

Comment: Another option that is sometimes useful is to use ToExpression to do some new parsing *during* evaluation: (Begin["cc`"]; With[{s = ToExpression["x"]}, s = 1]; End[];)

Comment: Brett, is there any way to use `$NewSymbol` to force a symbol to be created in a specific context, and by extension not in the default one?

Comment: @Andrew, why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard probably not, since `$NewSymbol` doesn't influence what happens to that symbol during further evaluation.  I was doing to do something similar to what @Andrew said.  When using explicit context names becomes cumbersome, one can put everything in an .m file and read that.  The way to make the palette self-contained is perhaps to use a huge string instead of an .m file, and read from that.  **Unless** there's maybe some reliable notebook/front-end wizardry to include the code in the palette notebook and evaluate the definitions when the palette is loaded.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I guess this deserves a separate question. I don't have a lot of experience with the notebook and the front end.

Comment: @Szabolcs actually, it has already been asked, but it was never resolved.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167406/moving-contexts-with-newsymbol-in-mathematica

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think it's clear from the documentation example for `$NewSymbol` using `Print` that the output of the function isn't used for creating the new symbol (otherwise all the new symbols would be `Null`.)

Answer (score 3):

For your second question, I refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824861/getting-current-context-from-within-package/4827624#4827624) answer of mine, which effectively automates the steps you outlined (with the `ParseTimeNameSpaceWrapper` function). It may need more work to make it more robust, but that could be a starting point. I use this stuff myself on occasion.

Comment: `ParseTimeNameSpaceWrapper` still doesn't get around the fact that the context of symbols is decided at parse-time, i.e. if I do `ParseTimeNameSpaceWrapper[x]`, that `x` will still be interpreted as ``Global`x``, not as ``MyLocalizedContext`x``. After understanding that the context is chosen at parse-time, I think there's no other way but to force a re-parse by either putting some code in a string and using `ToExpression`, or reading it from a package (or just writing the contexts explicitly as Brett suggests, but that's a lot of work for longer code).

Comment: @Szabolcs I see. Perhaps this thread might be of interest to you, regarding the parsing stage:  http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/c1f4ab24db8a8542

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference:

```
(Begin["cc`"]; Evaluate[Symbol["x"]] = 1; End[])

cc`x
```

> ```
> 1
> ```